# How do I transform this code into something simpler that I am more familiar with?

Tags: java, events, mouseevent, actionevent

I am currently in my first year of Java and have stumbled upon this code on the internet about a battleship game. What I would like to do is understand this code in more simple code. The part that confuses me is the first line: "computerGameBoard = new GameBoard(true, event ->". I am familiar with buttons and how they have action events, but how does this code compare to that and is it possible to turn this into a similar action event to a button? Could I split it into another method? Thanks in advance. Also note that the line of code below should be attached to the code segment, but its not.

```
    computerGameBoard = new GameBoard(true, event ->
    {
        if (!playing)
            return;

        BoardSquare boardsquare = (BoardSquare) event.getSource();
        if (boardsquare.wasHit)
            return;

        AIMove = !boardsquare.fire();
         System.out.println("enemyBoard shipcount:"+computerGameBoard.shipcount);
        if (computerGameBoard.shipcount == 0) {
            System.out.println("Winner!");

        }

        if (AIMove)
            AI1();
    });
```

Comment: This seems more like a question for Code Review

Comment: This sounds primarily like a question about lambdas and how they work -- it's not actually meaningfully different from traditional action listeners, it's just using a lambda to implement them.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.  If you do not want it, you can use the contact us page to ask it to be dissociated from your account.

Answer (score 2):

An example of onClickListener() without lambda:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

can be rewritten with lambda:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    // do something here
});
```

So your code is using Lambda expression (Java 8 feature)